# How to alway allow HTTP OPTION request in istio?

Tags: istio

We've designed our API to use Istio JWT authentication which is mandatory and at the same time we've used the CORS. The problem is our JS code will do ajax call and HTTP Option pre-flight request will be called without JWT Authorization header. Unfornately the pre-flight request will be blocked by Istio. How to solve it?

Comment: You can use [VirtualService CorsPolicy](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/virtual-service/#CorsPolicy).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I think [Service Entry](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/v1alpha3/service-entry/) will solve this.

> `ServiceEntry` enables adding additional entries into Istio’s internal service registry, so that auto-discovered services in the mesh can access/route to these manually specified services. A service entry describes the properties of a service (DNS name, VIPs, ports, protocols, endpoints). These services could be external to the mesh (e.g., web APIs) or mesh-internal services that are not part of the platform’s service registry (e.g., a set of VMs talking to services in Kubernetes).

Service Entry for your example might look like the following:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-svc-https
spec:
  hosts:
  - api.foobar.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http
  resolution: DNS
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not solve my problem. In ServiceEntry you could specify the protocol - 'HTTP' in my case, but you cannot specify the HTTP method - actually it's 'OPTIONS'. My requirement is ALWAYS allowing the access of HTTP OPTIONS method whatever the HTTP URL is.

Comment: @YoufaMao, I don't think this is possible in istio. You would need to use custom nginx controller.